# Multiple Assignment to Array with Non Contiguous Indices

Tags: ruby, arrays

Ruby newbie here.  How can I assign multiple elements to an array where the indices are not contiguous? I have an array with length 1000, I want the indices 30,40,50...90 to be assigned the strings `["thirty", "fourty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]`.  My attempt of doing it is this:

```
tableWords = Array.new(1000)
tableWords[(30..90).step(10).to_a] = ["thirty", "fourty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]
```

I don't think array assignment in Ruby works this way, but I can't figure out how to do it.  Googling only tells me how to do multiple array assignment when the ranges are contiguous, e.g. 1,2,3,4,...30.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
indices = ["thirty", "fourty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]    
(30..90).step(10).each_with_index {|a, i| tableWords[a] = indices[i]}
```